# jQuery delete row from SQL (button) not working

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have a table of notes on a page.  I want the user to be able to add and delete notes dynamically.  I have the add notes feature working, but I am having trouble with the delete notes feature.  I can get the row to fade out on click of the delete button, but I cannot get the row to delete from the database.  Here is my code:

HTML:

```
            <td class='deleteCell'>                                         
                <input id=$noteID type='submit' class='delBtn' value='Delete'>        
            </td>                                                           
            <td class='dateCell'>                                           
                <p class='dateText'> $noteDate </p>                         
            </td>                                                           
            <td class='noteCell'>                                           
                <p class='noteText'> $noteText </p>                         
            </td>                                                           
        </tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".delBtn").click(function() {
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.post("deleteNote.php" , {id : del_id},
        function() {
            parent.fadeOut('slow',
                function() {
                    $(this).remove();
                }) ;
        }) ;
}) ;
```

deleteNote.php:

```
<?php
include( 'includes/sql_link.php' )  ;


if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $post  =   mysqli_real_escape_string ( $db , $_POST['id'] ) ;
    $query = " DELETE FROM Room_Notes WHERE Note_ID LIKE LIKE '{$post}%'";

    if(query($query)) {
        echo "YES";
    }
    else {
        echo "NO";
    }
}
else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

It removes the row from the table but not the database.  everytime I refresh the page

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Just updated with escape string, I am not sure if thats what you were referring too.  I am still really new at this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have two "LIKE"'s in your query.

```
 DELETE FROM Room_Notes WHERE Note_ID LIKE '{$post}%'
```

(Would this not be better as a = anyway?)

Let me know the outcome of the alert :)

---

Try changing your post request to this:

```
$.post( "deleteNote.php", { id: del_id } );
```

Alternatively you could change all POST parameters in deleteNote.php to GET parameters

Comment: Hi Corbin,  I updated my SQL with the `=` and I added the alert to my jQuery.  The alert provides the correct ID before fading out the row, but still no delete from database.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: chnaged my post request and it broke it.  wouldn't even alert the id anymore.  tried to change post to get on deleteNote.php and it again, would not work.  I am so frustrated with this ha

Comment: Look at my profile if you want to contact me further, I can't help you without a demo